# how to keep RecyclerView always scroll bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I Use Recyclerview Replace with list view
I want to keep Recyclerview always scroll bottom.

ListView can use this method `setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL)`

RecyclerView I use method `smoothScrollToPosition(myAdapter.getItemCount() - 1)`

but when Soft keyboard Pop ,its replace RecyclerView content.

Comment: Did you resolve the problem at last? I find setReverseLayout to true will cause the item displayed from top to bottom, it's not suitable for chat.

Comment: you can try my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43647835/6482350

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is because RV thinks its reference point is TOP and when keyboard comes up, RV's size is updated by the parent and RV keeps its reference point stable. (thus keeps the top position at the same location)

You can set [LayoutManager#ReverseLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)) to true in which case RV will layout items from the end of the adapter.

e.g. adapter position 0 is at the bottom, 1 is above it etc...

This will of course require you to reverse the order of your adapter.

I'm not sure but setting [stack from end](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean)) may also give you the same result w/o reordering your adapter.

Comment: thanks,you solve my problem. i use reverseLayout param

Comment: The layout contents got reversed, but the list didn't scroll to the end. Even stackFromBottom didn't help.

Comment: Just an addition: Sometimes setting `stackFromEnd` in XML is **not** working while calling the method on code does.

Comment: If you set both stackFromEnd=true and setReverseLayout=true it doesn't work. Does anyone know any workaround?

Comment: @LuccasCorrea How did you get it to work? I used llm.setStackFromEnd(true); and mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(mItemsList.size() - 1); on adding an item at the bottom of the list. Let me know if you found any other way.

Comment: mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); really helped for keyboard opening fix recyclerView.. Thanks man.. :)

Comment: In my case, I set both `reverseLayout` and `stackFromEnd` to true, and sort my data reversely, which works just like a Chat list.

Comment: I set `reverseLayout` and `stackFromEnd` and sorted the data reversely - everything got reversed but it doesn't scroll to the end.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to keep the scroll position anchored to the bottom of the `RecyclerView`, it's useful in chat apps. just call `setStackFromEnd(true)` to on the `LinearLayoutManager` to make the keyboard keep the list items anchored on the bottom (the keyboard) and not the top.

Comment: Works only for the first time for me...and yes I am making a chat app

Comment: This worked. Setting this in the xml file didn't work.

Comment: @larrytech wasn't it clear from the answer that should be invoked on the `LinearLayoutManager`?

Comment: It doesn't work. It's reversed but it doesn't scroll to the bottom.

Answer (score 6):

```
recyclerView.scrollToPosition(getAdapter().getItemCount()-1);
```

Comment: This doesn't work well when users scroll up a bit and wish to stay same for the whatever last visible item.

Answer (score 5):

I have faced the same problem and I solved it using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android?lq=1). It is used to detect whether soft keyboard is open or not and if it is open, just call the `smoothScrollToPosition()` method.

> A much simpler solution is to give your activity's root view a known ID, say '@+id/activityRoot', hook a GlobalLayoutListener into the ViewTreeObserver, and from there calculate the size diff between your activity's view root and the window size:

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
    if (heightDiff > 100) { 
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(myAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
    }
 }
});
```

Easy!

Comment: this works best out of all the answers on this page, however, when you implement the code be sure to check that `myAdapter.getItemCount() > 0` Otherwise when the app starts up without items in the list, it'll crash because it tries to scroll to position -1

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced same problem. But following code help me. I hope this is useful.

In this staus is arraylist.

```
 recyclerView.scrollToPosition(staus.size()-1);
```

next one is:-
In This you can use adapter class

```
   recyclerView.scrollToPosition(showAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem myself and I ended up creating my own LayoutManager to solve it. It's a pretty straightforward solution that can be broken down into three steps:

1. Set `stackFromEnd` to true.
2. Determine whether `forceTranscriptScroll` should be set to true whenever `onItemsChanged` is called. Per the documentation, `onItemsChanged` gets called whenever the contents of the adapter changes. If `transcriptMode` is set to `Disabled`, `forceTranscriptScroll` will always be `false`, if it's set to `AlwaysScroll`, it will always be `true`, and if it's set to `Normal`, it will only be true if the last item in the adapter is completely visible.
3. In `onLayoutCompleted`, scroll to the last item in the list if `forceTranscriptScroll` is set to `true` and the last item in the list isn't already completely visible.

Below is the code that accomplishes these three steps:

```
import android.content.Context
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class TranscriptEnabledLinearLayoutManager(context: Context, transcriptMode: TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.Normal) :
    LinearLayoutManager(context) {

    enum class TranscriptMode {
        Disabled, Normal, AlwaysScroll
    }

    private var transcriptMode: TranscriptMode = TranscriptMode.Disabled
        set(value) {
            field = value
            // Step 1
            stackFromEnd = field != TranscriptMode.Disabled
        }

    private var forceTranscriptScroll = false

    init {
        this.transcriptMode = transcriptMode
    }

    // Step 2
    override fun onItemsChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
        super.onItemsChanged(recyclerView)
        forceTranscriptScroll = when (transcriptMode) {
            TranscriptMode.Disabled -> false
            TranscriptMode.Normal -> {
                findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == itemCount - 1
            }
            TranscriptMode.AlwaysScroll -> true
        }
    }

    // Step 3
    override fun onLayoutCompleted(state: RecyclerView.State?) {
        super.onLayoutCompleted(state)
        val recyclerViewState = state ?: return

        if (!recyclerViewState.isPreLayout && forceTranscriptScroll) {
            // gets the position of the last item in the list. returns if list is empty
            val lastAdapterItemPosition = recyclerViewState.itemCount.takeIf { it > 0 }
                ?.minus(1) ?: return
            val lastCompletelyVisibleItem = findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()
            if (lastCompletelyVisibleItem != lastAdapterItemPosition ||
                recyclerViewState.targetScrollPosition != lastAdapterItemPosition) {
                scrollToPositionWithOffset(lastAdapterItemPosition, 0)
            }
            forceTranscriptScroll = false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this questions is a bit old, seems like no answer is correct. I think what you need here is to listen to the Adapter changes and then scroll to the bottom on every detected change.

This is a working example of it

```kotlin
yourAdapter?.registerAdapterDataObserver(object : AdapterDataObserver() {
    override fun onChanged() {
        yourRecyclerView?.smoothScrollToPosition(yourAdapter?.itemCount ?: 0)
    }
})
```