# Configure RecyclerView to work as a chat

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-recyclerview

To enable chat-style scrolling in a List View, we can use the following properties:

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ....
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:transcriptMode="normal" />
```

It is a simple and efficient way to create a chat.
How can we do the same thing with a recycler view ? I did not find any simple solution.

Regards,

Comment: you can try my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43647835/6482350

Answer (score 19, accepted):

RecyclerView has a `stackFromEnd` attribute.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView" 
        android.support.v7.recyclerview:stackFromEnd ="true"/>
```

Or you can do it through code

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks.It worked. This is the equivalent to stackFromBottom. But which property has the similiar effect of android:transcriptMode ? It guarantees that the listview only scrolls down if the user is looking to the last element of data set.

Comment: I think similar effect to transcriptMode can be achieved through code by using `setReverseLayout()`. Check out my edit.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. I will test it and will post here if it worked or not.

Comment: Only added `StackFromEnd` did the trick. If you reverse layout, you need to reverse your queries and everything

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know the "setStackFromEnd" this whole time.

Answer (score 2):

***add these statements;***

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/chat_list_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
                    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
                    android:transcriptMode="normal" />
```

*and add into layout manager*

```
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```