# ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS SCROLL in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

As we know we have option `ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS SCROLL` which will scroll to bottom.

> The list will automatically scroll to the bottom, no matter what items
>   are currently visible.

Now we are having `RecyclerView`, does there any similar option of this in `RecyclerView`?

Comment: `RecyclerView` doesn't  have that option

Comment: @PiyushGupta yes, but does there anything similar to it?

Comment: Yes you can use _smoothScrollToPosition_

Comment: give a look at it, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634927/configure-recyclerview-to-work-as-a-chat

Comment: you can see my answer for help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43647889/6482350

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
recycler_view.scrollToPosition(int position);
```

where position is index of row in recycle view.